# Insert Lines between rows and columns(Gridlines/cell-Borders) to look like Table without any library/styler

Tags: python, dataframe, border

Let's say I have a DataFrame...

```
data = {'Col1': [20, 15, 10, 5, 20, 17], 'Col2': [11, 6, 3, 16, 21, 8], 'Col3': [2, 17, 12, 7, 22, 9],'Col4': [3, 8, 13, 18, 3, 23], 'Col5': [4, 19, 8, 11, 6, 20]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Now I want to print this DataFrame in table format by simply inserting lines between rows and columns(Gridlines/cell-borders) without using any library or styler to get output like a table in Excel with border.

I tried like below...

```
def bordergen(df):
    col_widths = [max(len(str(col)), max(df[col].astype(str).str.len())) for col in df.columns]
    header = '_'.join(['_' * (width + 2) for width in col_widths])
    print(header)
    
    for col in df.columns:
        print(f'| {col:<{col_widths[df.columns.get_loc(col)]}} ', end='')
    print('|')
    print(header)

    for _, row in df.iterrows():
        for col in df.columns:
            print(f'| {row[col]:<{col_widths[df.columns.get_loc(col)]}} ', end='')
        print('|')
        print(header)

bordergen(df)
```

Here is my expected output looks like...
[image: output expected]

How can I make the lines to touch each other so that there is no gap between them making a box around all cells ???

Answer (score 0):

This is likely what you are looking for.

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'Col1': [20, 15, 10, 5, 20, 17], 'Col2': [11, 6, 3, 16, 21, 8], 'Col3': [2, 17, 12, 7, 22, 9],
        'Col4': [3, 8, 13, 18, 3, 23], 'Col5': [4, 19, 8, 11, 6, 20]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
s
def bordergen(df):
    # Calculate column widths
    col_widths = [max(len(str(col)), max(df[col].astype(str).str.len())) for col in df.columns]

    header = '+'.join(['-' * width for width in col_widths])

    print(header)

    for col in df.columns:
        print(f'|{col:<{col_widths[df.columns.get_loc(col)]}}', end='')
    print('|')
    print(header)

    for _, row in df.iterrows():
        for col in df.columns:
            print(f'|{row[col]:<{col_widths[df.columns.get_loc(col)]}}', end='')
        print('|')

bordergen(df)
```

Output:

```
----+----+----+----+----
|Col1|Col2|Col3|Col4|Col5|
----+----+----+----+----
|20  |11  |2   |3   |4   |
|15  |6   |17  |8   |19  |
|10  |3   |12  |13  |8   |
|5   |16  |7   |18  |11  |
|20  |21  |22  |3   |6   |
|17  |8   |9   |23  |20  |
```